# C 'TRUE;' Statement

Tags: c, language-features

I came across some code written in C that looks like this:

```
if (file == NULL)
     TRUE; /* <-- What does that mean? */
```

I think that it is another way of saying:

```
if (file == NULL);
```

But am I missing something, and is there a reason to do it the first way as opposed to the second way?

UPDATE:

Doing some digging, TRUE is defined as such:

```
#define TRUE !0
```

Comment: So, what is `TRUE` defined to be? (inb4 "that's deep") This is like opening a question and saying "I saw asdjahek, what does it mean?" We don't have a clue.

Comment: The identifier "TRUE" does not have any predefined meaning in C. In order to tell you what this does, we would have to see its definition.

Comment: @GMan - good comment. Answer hinges on this, as well as what follows this code, which could be an `else`. btw whatever the answer, this is obfuscatory and should be replaced by something that does not prompt a q on SO.

Comment: C only defined a macro named 'true' in stdbool.h

Comment: Also knowing a bit about the context would be nice. For example, it could help us know that the developer didn't just leave this in his code because he meant to go back and implement error handling but didn't get around to it.

Comment: I think that `TRUE` is defined as 1, but I am not sure..

Comment: @Richard:  As has been said, this question cannot be answered unless you state what `TRUE` expands to.  `#define TRUE 1` is very different from `#define TRUE abort()`

Comment: @James I dont think that `TRUE` is defined as `abort()` :), that wouldn't make sense...

Comment: @Richard: this already doesn't make sense, that's why you're asking about it. You'll have more luck looking up the macro in the source than asking passing strangers ;-)

Comment: @Richard: Look it up... In any case, it's crap code.

Comment: TRUE is probably being defined in a header file somewhere (eg. #define TRUE 1). Please search your header files for it and report its definition back here.

Comment: life lesson. just because something would be stupid, it doesn't mean  somebody didn't do it

Comment: It means someone has been playing silly buggers. Probably with macros, which makes those buggers *extra* silly.

Comment: @michael ill bet you are right, please make that an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess - I suspect at some point in history someone wanted to set a breakpoint on that TRUE line.

I've worked with debuggers where doing that might have been easier than trying to set a conditional breakpoint.  But it's been a long, long time since that might have been true.  I still find myself doing something similar in some environments if the condition I want to break on involves a function call or if a conditional breakpoint slows things down too much (that happens a lot on embedded targets where evaluation the condition in the debugger involves a lot of communication over the JTAG link).

However, that do-nothing code shouldn't have made it into version control.

Comment: I suspect that that Is probably the intent of the code, after looking at the code in depth and with all the help from everyone, thank you!

Comment: But assuming that `#define TRUE !0` will there any code be produced by the compiler for the statement `TRUE;` even on debug build?

Comment: `!0` can be evaluated at compile time, and any sane compiler (even for 8-bit micros back in the day) would do at least that much. Some of those, however, would happily compile `1;` as `MOV AL,#1` or the equivalent. Even with the "optimizer" enabled, as I recall for a 6809 compiler I used many years ago. A good compiler would vanish the whole condition after noticing the constant non-volatile expression as a statement.

Comment: Keynslug: you're right (at least for Visual Studio).  The 'do nothing' statement often has to be something a bit more complex (like maybe `file = (FILE* volatile) file;`).

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason to write like this is to get rid of annoying compiler warnings.

It is true for MSVC that the second statement will cause compiler to warn about `empty controlled statement` or something like. However `TRUE;` is a regular valid non-empty statement.

Comment: I can think of better ways of improving the line `if (file == NULL);`, assuming `file` is the name of a variable. If it's followed by an `else`, perhaps the original author was unaware of `!=` ;-)

Comment: But if he put it there as a kind of `TODO:`, then it would be wisier to let the compiler generate the warning.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a statement with no effect, but what is TRUE defined to be (It isn't standard)? If it is just 1 as expected, this has no effect. There is no reason to do either of these.